# Order of entry in a Nifi PG when multiple in-coming connections to same port with OldestFirstPrioritizer

Tags: apache-nifi

So I have a PG that allows only a single flow file in it. No cluster nifi.

It gets multiple incoming connections (4 in my case) to a same input port.

Till now all the connections in my flow were of the form FIFO prioritizer.

Now I am wondering if I should be using OldestFlowFileFirst prioritizer on all the incoming connections on this single flow file PG. If I do this and all 4 connections get a flow file, I was wondering which will win.

Are the prioritizers only valid for their respective connections and only prioritizing flowfiles in that queue or over all of the 4 queues the OldestFlowFileFirst prioritizer will take precedence.

Regards

I suppose I could test but was hoping someone knew the answer already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should use a funnel [1] to combine the four queues into a single queue. The single queue should then have the prioritized assigned and connected to the Input Port within the child Process Group.

[1] https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html

Comment: The funnel itself has no properties, just the outgoing connection from the funnel will do the trick you mean.  I created it, sounds like what I need. Thanks.